# search content inside files stored in blob fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

The database of my application stores files in a `FILESTRAM` blob field. I have a dedicated table where i keep all files.

THis is the table (`DOCUMENT` is the blob field):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DOC_FILES](
    [ID_DOC_FILE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DOCUMENT] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
    [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [FILE_SIZE] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DOC_FILES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_DOC_FILE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [MyDatabase],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [MyDatabase]
```

What i'd like to perform is a search inside the files.

I would like to target files as pdf, doc, docx, rtf, txt.

Is it possible to do a query like this:

```
SELECT ID_DOC_FILES FROM DOC_FILES
WHERE DOCUMENT *CONTAINS* 'my search string' //*CONTAINS* of course is just for demonstration...
```

??

it should return all the IDs of the pfd, doc, docx, rt, txt files containing 'my search string'.

A workaround could be to create an `INDEXED_CONTENT` field where to save as text the content of the file (i can process one by one all the files to extract text).

Anyway before doing this I would like to be sure that searching inside blobs it is not possible.

Thank you.

Comment: When you get the location of the document you could then us XP_cmdshell tp parse theiugh the file to get what you need.